# Javascript: API call with Certs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, node-modules

I have to make API call using 'sync-request' node module using certs (.cert & .pem file) which are given to us. Whenever I am trying to make a call - it gives error message as - Unable to verify the first certificate.

I have tried using agentOptions or importing 'ssl-root-cas' node module. But it gives same above error. I am not sure if, I am passing values correctly or not.

```
let request = require('sync-request');
let crt_file = fs.readFileSync('someFilePath.cer', ascii);
let pem_file = fs.readFileSync('someFilePath.pem', ascii);
let apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/getDetails';
let agentOptions = {
  maxCachedSessions: 0,
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
  securityOptions: 'SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3',
  ciphers: 'ALL',
  key: crt_file,
  cert: pem_file,
  Passphrase: 'London1!'
}

let response = request('GET', apiUrl, agentOptions);
```

I want to get success response with use of certs. The above agentOptions is something which I googled and tried to include.

NOTE: I do not want to use NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `request` node module being deprecated, `got` provides excellent approach. This works for me.

```
const got = require('got');
const crypto  = require('crypto');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');

const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
        secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function: (baseString, key) => crypto.createHmac('sha1', key).update(baseString).digest('base64')
});

const token = {
    key: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    secret: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
};

const url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';

got(url, {
    headers: oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize({url, method: 'GET'}, token)),
    responseType: 'json'
});
```